# Implementing direct as2 connection from legacy as400 system

Tags: sftp, ibm-midrange, actionscript-2, edi, cleo

we work in EDI from legacy as400 system/Gentran mapping tool and we send/recieve with our EDI vendors thru VAN connection. One of our new EDI vendor ask for direct as2 connection or SFTP file transfer as they do not accept VAN due to security issues. Which should i choose - AS2 or SFTP? When there is already as2 connection and as2 certificate with our VAN, should i install seperate as2 client software for this new vendor or can i use the same connection for both? How to implement it? Note: we also use Cleo VLtrader for FTP file transfers.

Comment: Please clarify your abbreviations: VAN, AS2. Then I could possibly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple AS2 connections out of the same software.  You'll need to know their URL, their port, their certificate and AS2 ID and what security parameters they want around the connection.

They can use the same inbound connection that you have set up with your VAN.

Ultimately, both protocols are secure.  Both should be "set it and forget it" for you.  It's really want you want to support and maintain.